# Google Cloud Platform VM unable to SSH from local (Permission denied (publickey))

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I tried to ssh to Google Cloud VM from My MacBook terminal, which worked just fine yesterday. 
I have my public keys and private keys the way it should be from my understandings.

When I try to connect as bellow,

```
XXXXXXXX-MacBook-Pro:~ xxxxxxxx$ ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa xxxxxxxx@12.345.678.910 -v
```

The error debug goes as bellow. (User names, IP Address etc. are masked)

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 12.345.678.910 [12.345.678.910] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 12.345.678.910:22 as 'xxxxxxxx'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
debug1: Host '12.345.678.910' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: .ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-xxxxx,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-xxxxxx,ecdsa-sha2-xxxxxx>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: .ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
xxxxxxxxxx@12.345.678.910: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The "Server host key" and the "Offering public key: .ssh/id_rsa RSA" was different. However I copy & pasted .ssh/id_rsa.pub from my local and the authorized_keys in Google Cloud VM had the same public key attached.

What causes this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe capture exactly all the steps you performed.  I think I am hearing you say you copied id_rsa.pub from one PC to another.  Don't you need the private key (not the public key) on your local PC to prove to the target (SSH) that you are are who you claim to be because you posses the private key?

Comment: **1**. Is it possible for you to connect to VM with `gcloud compute ssh` command? **2**. Have you tried to connect to this VM from via Console web UI?